# How can I cycle through a set of variable assigned enum values in java

Tags: java, enums

I'm working on a project in school. I've found a lot of ways to cycle through enum values but in all of my searches I haven't found a way to cycle through a set of variables that hold enum values.

Some context: The project is a TicTacToe game. We were given the enum and a set of methods we need to create to complete the project. We are not allowed to change the method signature and must make it work within the provided construct. We're also limited to what we've learned in class so far, which means lists maps and arrays aren't an option. The enum holds 3 values- X, O, and EMPTY. Then we have 9 variables that represent the 9 positions on the game board.

```
    public enum Marker
{
    EMPTY,
    X,
    O
};

private static Marker position1 = Marker.EMPTY;
private static Marker position2 = Marker.EMPTY;
private static Marker position3 = Marker.EMPTY;
private static Marker position4 = Marker.EMPTY;
private static Marker position5 = Marker.EMPTY;
private static Marker position6 = Marker.EMPTY;
private static Marker position7 = Marker.EMPTY;
private static Marker position8 = Marker.EMPTY;
private static Marker position9 = Marker.EMPTY;

private static Marker turn = Marker.X;
```

I'm working on a method that checks if there's a tie. So, I need to cycle through the position variables and test that each one != Marker.EMPTY. I was about to write a huge conditional statement and while I'm sure it would work, there has to be a better way. After about a half hour of searching- here I am. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered storing them in a `List`, `Map`, or array?

Comment: I wish I could use those tools. Unfortunately, the constraints of the assignment prevent me from doing so.

Comment: In a comment on my answer, you wrote "Thanks for the reply. I wish I could use an array, but I can't."  What data structures _do_ you have available to you then?  What about iteration constructs?  Can you use `for` loops?  (If you can, what would you actually use them for, since you don't have anything to iterate _over_?)

Comment: I can use for loops as well as while, do while, if/else, and switch.

Comment: I think the problem is where you say that you want to iterate through a "set of variables."  That means that you have to group them together somehow.  Is it the intention of your assignment that you're not allowed to do this?  If so, then a large `if` statement is all you have left.

Comment: Apart from this problem, what have you used `for` loops _for_?  Sure, all the looping constructs are interchangeable, but `for` loops are usually introduced for iterating over collections of things (e.g., `for ( int i=0; i < arr.length; i++ ) { /* do something with arr[i] */ }`.  What have you been using them for, if not for arrays or other collections?

Comment: @bstempi Yeah, unfortunately we're not allowed to manipulate the enum. The large if was the first thing that popped in my mind but I thought there would be an easier way. I guess there is...but I can't use it. I guess I'll go with the if. I wish I could have used your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @rustan13 Be sure to use boolean conditions; you don't need to use a bunch of `if/else if/.../else`.  I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Using an array or `Collection` of `Marker` is not manipulating the enum.  `Marker` is left alone in Joshua Taylor's original answer.

Comment: I would not think that using Reflection to iterate over the static field definitions named "position"+i where i goes from 1 to 9 would be an acceptable solution in this case. It would be overkill, yet it is available in case you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't use any sort of collection, you probably want to use some boolean operators.  I.e, something like the following.  The board is full if none of the positions is `Marker.EMPTY`, so you can simply return `position1 != Marker.EMPTY && position2 != Marker.EMPTY && ...;`.  It's not all that pretty, but it's still much more concise than big `if/else if/.../else` block.

```
private static boolean isBoardFull() {
  return position1 != Marker.EMPTY &&
         position2 != Marker.EMPTY &&
         position3 != Marker.EMPTY &&
         position4 != Marker.EMPTY &&
         position5 != Marker.EMPTY &&
         position6 != Marker.EMPTY &&
         position7 != Marker.EMPTY &&
         position8 != Marker.EMPTY &&
         position9 != Marker.EMPTY ;
}
```

You could also write this as "the board is full if it's NOT the case that SOME position IS empty":

```
private static boolean isBoardFull() {
  return !( position1 == Marker.EMPTY ||
            position2 == Marker.EMPTY ||
            position3 == Marker.EMPTY ||
            position4 == Marker.EMPTY ||
            position5 == Marker.EMPTY ||
            position6 == Marker.EMPTY ||
            position7 == Marker.EMPTY ||
            position8 == Marker.EMPTY ||
            position9 == Marker.EMPTY );
}
```

There are a few options that would be more appropriate, if other things were available.  For instance, you could use a `for` loop over an array containing the positions? (You could actually use an array, or anything that implements Iterable.) E.g., if you still needed to have the nine variables:

```
private static Marker position1 = Marker.EMPTY;
private static Marker position2 = Marker.EMPTY;
private static Marker position3 = Marker.EMPTY;
private static Marker position4 = Marker.EMPTY;
private static Marker position5 = Marker.EMPTY;
private static Marker position6 = Marker.EMPTY;
private static Marker position7 = Marker.EMPTY;
private static Marker position8 = Marker.EMPTY;
private static Marker position9 = Marker.EMPTY;
private static Marker positions[] = new Marker[] { position1, position2, position3,
                                                   position4, position5, position6,
                                                   position7, position8, position9 };

private static boolean isBoardFull() {
  for ( Marker position : positions ) {
    if ( position == Marker.EMPTY ) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Ideally though, you wouldn't have the nine variables, and you'd want something that didn't require knowing the number of positions in advance, and you'd work with just the array (or other Iterable, probably a ordered Collection):

```
private static Marker positions[9];
static { 
  for ( int i=0; i < positions.length; i++ ) {
    positions[i] = Marker.EMPTY;
  }
}
```

Even better, if you could use a Collection such as a List, you wouldn't even need to write an iteration, you'd just use [Collection.contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
private static List<Marker> positions = /* ... */;

private static boolean isBoardFull() {
  return !positions.contains( Marker.EMPTY );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wish I could use an array, but I can't.

Answer (score 0):

If you had an array of 9 Marker objects, or even a 2 dimensional array of 3 x 3 Marker objects, you would be able to loop through them.

Otherwise you could use reflection to find all the variables of type Marker, but this is probably well outside of the scope of your class.

Comment: You're correct- those are outside of my scope. We haven't gotten to arrays yet and I'm unfamiliar with reflection at this point in my programming journey.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have 9 separate position variables. Have one array of size 9.

```
private Marker positions = new Marker[9]; 

...
```

Then before you use them -

```
Arrays.fill(positions,Marker.EMPTY);

...
```

And later

```
for (Marker position : positions) {
   ...
}
```